# VisualForce DateFormat - how to display the Day

Tags: datetime, salesforce, datetime-format, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to format a date in VisualForce so that it looks like this:

```
Tuesday 02/22/11
```

I found this reference on stackoverflow:

> [How to format a date in VisualForce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516549/how-to-format-a-date-in-visualforce)

But I cannot determine what to put in the format string.

I tried using an `e` as referenced here:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

But when I do that:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'e'/'yy}">
        <apex:param value="{!od.PriceBookEntry.Product2.Start__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

I get a save error of:

> Save error:  The Date format pattern for  is invalid

---

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEE MM'/'yy}">
    <apex:param value="{!od.PriceBookEntry.Product2.Start__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEEE MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!od.PriceBookEntry.Product2.Start__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

Outputs:

Monday 10/02/1944

Comment: How do you get this formating to take the users timezone into account and display that time in their local timezone instead of GMT?